# DBeaver show nothing for "show server output"

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

[image]

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mct.hello_world()
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
RAISE NOTICE 'Hello world';
END;
$function$
;

SELECT hello_world();
```

What's wrong? I was expecting to get "Hello world" in the "Output" window, but there is nothing.